# In magento how to write the code for displaying customfield attribute value in breadcrumbs

Tags: magento

In my magento admin I have created a customfield using attribute as product_title in my product page.Since i am using very long product name i have created this attribute in admin to get the smaller title for product name and make it to display in breadcrumbs instead of product name.

I have updated the code in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php like mentioned below

```
if ($this->getProduct()) {
                $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getproduct_title());
            }
```

Now my requirement is if we didn't provide product_title means i have to get the breadcrumb value for product from the function getName()

```
$path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
```

How to write condition for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put condition `if and elase`

```
if($this->getProduct()->getproduct_title()!='')
{

$path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getproduct_title());
}
else
{
$path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());

}
```